# Does setting the experience filter do anything?

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

Even if I set the experience level of jobs I'm searching for to be junior to mid-level, I still get at least a quarter of listings asking for senior developers.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample URL for your search, and a sample URL for a listing that is returned by this search when it shouldn't?

Answer (score 5):

Upon using:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?c=usd&ms=Junior&mxs=MidLevel

I was suggested:

[Senior Java Software Architect (m/f)](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/217392/senior-java-software-architect-m-f-webtrekk-gmbh?so=i&pg=1&offset=2&ms=Junior&mxs=MidLevel)

---

This is probably because they have multiple levels listed:

> Experience level: **Mid-Level, Senior, Lead**

[image]

---

When using:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?c=usd&ms=Student&mxs=Junior

then I no longer receive that job listing.